# Скрипт на Python для бэкапа конфига Cisco

Tags: python, ssh, cisco

Пытаюсь написать скрипт для бэкапа конфига *cisco* через *ssh*  и модуль *paramiko*. Сам скрипт:

```
import paramiko
import datetime
import sys
import os
import time

#now = datetime.datetime.now()

host = "192.168.100.1" 
user = "user" 
password = "password"
secret = "password"
port=22

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=password, port=port)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('enable')
stdin.write(secret +'\n')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('term len 0')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('sh ver')
a = stdout.read()
print a
f = open('testing.txt', 'a')
f.write(a)
f.close()
client.close()
```

при запуске выдает

```
C:\Python27>python.exe d:\cisco_backup_v0.1.py
SSH connection established to 192.168.100.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\cisco_backup_v0.1.py", line 23, in <module>
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('term len 0')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 341, in exec_com
mand
    chan = self._transport.open_session()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 615, in open_
session
    max_packet_size=max_packet_size)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 731, in open_
channel
    raise e
EOFError
```

Версия *python 2.7*, запускаю под виндой. Если закомментировать эту строку, то ругается дальше. Пробовал без *enable* пароля просто снять `sh ver`, тогда все отлично.

В чем ошибка?

Comment: Попробуйте [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) - удобную обертку над ssh. Еще может быть полезным [это](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/55)

Comment: нужно [оболочку (shell) запустить, чтобы была возможность несколько команд исполнять в одной ssh сессии](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6203653/4279) .

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформите своё решение в отдельный ответ, так будет гораздо лучше видно, что ваша проблема решена, а также люди, столкнувшиеся с похожей задачей, смогут отблагодарить вас.

Answer (score 4):

Переделал с использованием `client.invoke_shell()` Вот скрипт

```
import sys
import time
import paramiko 
import os
import cmd



HOST = '192.168.100.1'
USER = 'user'
PASSWORD = 'password'
secret = 'password'

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(HOST, username=USER, password=PASSWORD)

chan = client.invoke_shell()
time.sleep(1)
chan.send('en\n')
chan.send(secret +'\n')
time.sleep(1)
chan.send('term len 0\n')
time.sleep(1)
chan.send('sh run\n')
time.sleep(10)
output = chan.recv(99999)
time.sleep(3)
print output
time.sleep(10)

client.close()
```